# Creating tokens from list of sentences is returning characters instead of words

Tags: python, text, nlp, nltk, tokenize

```
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize

text = open(path).read().lower().decode("utf8")
sent_tokenize_list = sent_tokenize(text)

tokens = [w for w in itertools.chain(*[sent for sent in sent_tokenize_list])]
```

The last line, "tokens", returns characters instead of words.

Why is this and how do I get it to return words instead? Especially considering doing it based on a list of sentences.

Comment: First decode, then lowercase. Otherwise you'll get incorrect behavior with non-ascii characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because [`sent_tokenize`](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html#nltk.tokenize.sent_tokenize) returns a list of string sentences and [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) chains iterables to a single iterable returning items one at a time from each until they're exhausted. In effect you've recombined the sentences to a single string and iterate over it in the list comprehension.

To create a single list of words from a list of sentences you can for example split and flatten:

```
tokens = [word for sent in sent_tokenize_list for word in sent.split()]
```

This does not handle punctuation, but your original attempt wouldn't either. Your original would work also with split:

```
tokens = [w for w in itertools.chain(*(sent.split()
                                       for sent in sent_tokenize_list))]
```

Note that you can use a generator expression instead of a list comprehension as arguments to unpack. Even better, use `chain.from_iterable`:

```
tokens = [w for w in itertools.chain.from_iterable(
    sent.split() for sent in sent_tokenize_list)]
```

For punctuation handling use [`nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize`](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html#nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize) instead of `str.split`. It'll return words and punctuation as separate items, and splits for example `I's` to `I` and `'s` (which of course is a good thing since they're in fact separate words, just contracted).

Comment: Use `nltk.word_tokenize()`, not `split()`. Punctuation and words are different tokens.

Answer (score 1):

May be you should to use `word_tokenize` instead of `sent_tokenize`?

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

text = open(path).read().lower().decode("utf8")
tokens = word_tokenize(text)
```

http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html#nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize

Comment: If all you want is a flat list of tokens regardless of sentence boundaries, this is the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, if the file is in 'utf8' and you're using Python2, it'll be better if you use the `encoding='utf8'` parameter in [`io.open()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html):

```
import io

from nltk import word_tokenize, sent_tokenize

with io.open('file.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8') as fin:
    document = []
    for line in fin:
        tokens += [word_tokenize(sent) for sent in sent_tokenize(line)]
```

If it's Python3, simply do:

```
from nltk import word_tokenize 

with open('file.txt', 'r') as fin:
    document = []
    for line in fin:
        tokens += [word_tokenize(sent) for sent in sent_tokenize(line)]
```

Do take a look at http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html

---

As for the tokenization, if we assume that each line contains some sort of paragraph that might be made up of one or more sentences, we would like to first initial a list to store the whole document:

```
document = []
```

Then we iterate through the lines and split the line up into sentences:

```
for line in fin:
    sentences = sent_tokenize(line)
```

Then we split the sentences up into the tokens:

```
token = [word_tokenize(sent) for sent in sent_tokenize(line)]
```

Since we want to update our document list to store the tokenized sentences, we use:

```
document = []
for line in fin:
    tokens += [word_tokenize(sent) for sent in sent_tokenize(line)]
```

---

**Not recommended!!!** (but still possible in one line):

```
alvas@ubi:~$ cat file.txt
this is a paragph. with many sentences.
yes, hahaah.. wahahha... 
alvas@ubi:~$ python
Python 2.7.11+ (default, Apr 17 2016, 14:00:29) 
[GCC 5.3.1 20160413] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import io
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> from nltk import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
>>> list(chain(*[[word_tokenize(sent) for sent in sent_tokenize(line)] for line in io.open('file.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8')]))
[[u'this', u'is', u'a', u'paragph', u'.'], [u'with', u'many', u'sentences', u'.'], [u'yes', u',', u'hahaah..', u'wahahha', u'...']]
```